# Cannot Change Launcher Opacity Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, transparency, tweak

I installed both Unity Tweak Tool and Compiz Config Settings Manager to try and make my launcher transparent in Ubuntu 16.04. Adjusting the launcher transparency in both of these programs had no change on the launcher's opacity/transparency. In Compiz I changed the 'maximised window' opacity to 0 and it immediately became clear so I am not sure why the launcher is not changing in opacity. I have also tried using the following get command to check the transparency and set command to set the transparency. The get command returns whatever I value I use the set command to set which makes sense but again the transparency is not visibly changing. Is a transparent launcher not possible in 16?

Comment: It's certainly possible here & likely for most. ccsm > Ubuntu unity plugin > Launcher > Launcher Opacity. You mention using a get & set command but never posted them...

Comment: Hi @doug, I managed to resolve my problem. It turns out I needed to install my GFX card drivers and now opacity controls are working fine. I didn't think of this solution at first as opacity was working on non-launcher things such as the tops of program windows. Should I delete my question or provide the answer myself for future readers? I'm still learning the ropes of Ask Ubuntu I'm afraid!

Comment: you might put some context into your question & then provide answer. Certainly seems specific to some hardware as I have never seen such an issue here (intel cpu/gpu, sometimes using nvidia mobile.